# Extract form value from HTML and send it with HTML form POST

Tags: html, forms, dom, post

First, I am trying to extract the username that is stored in the page source when the different user loads the page that contains the below book now button. So username changes for each user. Second, when the book now is pressed I want to send that username as the corresponding value to name="user[name]".

I can successfully extract the username that is loaded in the page source but having trouble to send it as a variable username value through the html post method.

I know I am doing something or everything wrong :) so any help is much appreciated.

Best.

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 
<head>
    <title>
        HTML DOM Input Text value Property
    </title>
</head>
 
<body style="text-align:center;">
 
    <h2>Extracted User</h2>
 
   <input type="text" name="Username" id="Username" autocomplete="off" value="yardicafe+emaartest@gmail.com" style="display:none;">
     
    <p id="username"></p>
     
    <!-- Script to return the Input Text value Property-->
    <script>
    let txt = document.getElementById("Username").value;
    document.getElementById("username").innerHTML = txt;
    </script>
    

<form method="post" action="https://www.supersaas.com/api/users">
  <input type="hidden" name="account" value="vavevu"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1234fk"/> <!-- The user has ID 1234 on your server's database -->
  <input type="text" name="user[name]" value="??????"/>  
  <input type="hidden" name="user[full_name]" value=""/>
  <input type="hidden" name="user[email]" value="yardicafe+emaartest@gmail.com"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="user[phone]" value=""/>
  <input type="hidden" name="user[address]" value=""/>
  <!-- you can add and remove fields on the "Access Control" screen -->
  <input type="hidden" name="checksum" value="d14c0e6398ef11a9a34cf513060e45a8"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="after" value="Scuba_Dalis"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Book now"/>
</form>
</body>
 
</html>
```

Comment: Unclear on what you're trying to do. You want the user to enter their username and have it sent to the server?

Comment: Thanks Zach. 
No, I want to eliminate users input. The username is already in the page source when user load that page. I want to extract that value (already done) and send it via form when user clicks the book now button. However, I can't send that value dynamically. We have 300 plus users...

Comment: Note that the [<input>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: Thanks Rob. I am not %100 expert on that, but I got that part of the html from https://www.supersaas.com/info/dev/user_api as a html snippet example. Maybe that’s why it has the closing slashes.